# JAVA Showing all elements in a index of a ArrayList

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, tostring

I am creating a menu-based program that generates invoices, this invoice is for monthly rent.
When the user selects a certain option, they are prompted for several user inputs which will be stored in variables(All doubles & 1 string).  these user inputs are being stored in an ArrayList.

I created a class BudgetInvoice where the variables are declared, I have my proper getters and setters as well as constructors.

I created a separate class InvoicerHub , where the ArrayList of type  is declared also where I will create functions to collect user input and store in the arrayList as well as displaying those elements in ArrayList.

In my main class, I am testing 2 functions (generateInvoice & showInvoice) where i will collect user input and the other function will display.

I am able to collect user input no problem but when I call the showInvoice function right after, nothing shows & the program terminates.

Below I will show the classes and functions in question as well as my main class as to get some insight on what might be going wrong here.

Appreciate the help!

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BudgetInvoice {

    protected double monthlyRent;
    protected double waterBill;
    protected double energyBill;
    protected double carRent; 
    protected double internetRent;
    protected String invoiceID;
     
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public double getMonthlyRent() {
        return monthlyRent;
    }

    public void setMonthlyRent(double monthlyRent) {
        this.monthlyRent = monthlyRent;
    }

    public double getWaterBill() {
        return waterBill;
    }

    public void setWaterBill(double waterBill) {
        this.waterBill = waterBill;
    }

    public double getEnergyBill() {
        return energyBill;
    }

    public void setEnergyBill(double energyBill) {
        this.energyBill = energyBill;
    }

    public double getCarRent() {
        return carRent;
    }

    public void setCarRent(double carRent) {
        this.carRent = carRent;
    }

    public double getInternetRent() {
        return internetRent;
    }

    public void setInternetRent(double internetRent) {
        this.internetRent = internetRent;
    }

    public String getInvoiceID() {
        return invoiceID;
    }

    public void setInvoiceID(String invoiceID) {
        this.invoiceID = invoiceID;
    }
    
    public BudgetInvoice (double monthlyRent, double waterBill, double energyBill , double carRent, double internetRent, String invoiceID) 
    {
        this.monthlyRent = monthlyRent; 
        this.waterBill = waterBill;
        this.energyBill = energyBill;
        this.carRent = carRent;
        this.internetRent = internetRent;
        this.invoiceID = invoiceID;
    }

    public BudgetInvoice() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "BudgetInvoice [monthlyRent=" + monthlyRent + ", waterBill=" + waterBill + ", energyBill=" + energyBill
                + ", carRent=" + carRent + ", internetRent=" + internetRent + ", invoiceID=" + invoiceID + ", myScan="
                + myScan + "]";
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class InvoicerHub extends BudgetInvoice{
    protected ArrayList <BudgetInvoice> InvoiceHub ;
    
    public InvoicerHub() 
    {
        InvoiceHub = new ArrayList<BudgetInvoice>();
    }
    
    public InvoicerHub(ArrayList<BudgetInvoice> InvoiceHub) 
    {
        super();
        this.InvoiceHub = InvoiceHub;
    }
    
    public void generateInvoice (BudgetInvoice b ) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your Monthly Rent");
        double rent = myScan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Your monthly Water bill");
        double waterBill = myScan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your Energy Costs");
        double energyBill = myScan.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Enter your monthly car payment");
        double carPayment = myScan.nextDouble();        
        
        System.out.println("Enter your monthly Internet costs");
        double internetBill = myScan.nextDouble();
        myScan.nextLine(); // to catch the enter input 
        
        System.out.println("Enter your desired Invoice ID");
        String invoiceID = myScan.nextLine();
        
        BudgetInvoice B = new BudgetInvoice ( rent , waterBill, energyBill, carPayment, internetBill, invoiceID);
        
        InvoiceHub.add(B);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "InvoicerHub [InvoiceHub=" + InvoiceHub + "]";
    }

    public String showInvoice() 
    {
        String temp = "Here is your Invoice";
        
        for(BudgetInvoice p : InvoiceHub) 
        {
             temp += p.toString();
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        InvoicerHub myInvoice = new InvoicerHub();
        
        myInvoice.generateInvoice(myInvoice);
        myInvoice.showInvoice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are not printing the result of the showInvoice() method.
Be careful that you are returning a String and not printing inside the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of `showInvoice` should do just that (i.e show the invoice).  The print statement should be in that method and the method should have a return type of `void`.  Otherwise, you might want to rename the method to something more meaningful like `getFormattedInvoice()`

You could also modify your `toString()` method to properly format the invoice for printing.  Then you could just print the invoice by simply printing the object.

Note:  When overriding methods like `toString()` it is good practice to precede them with an `@Override` annotation.  This will ensure your method signature matches the signature of the overridden method.  Doing so can often help prevent debugging issues by catching improper signatures at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        InvoicerHub myInvoice = new InvoicerHub();
        
        myInvoice.generateInvoice(myInvoice);
        System.out.println(myInvoice.showInvoice());
    }
}
```